# Display nothing when insert third record laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm developing a web app project of my client where people can ask there questions, like stack-overflow, I inserted 1 record manually into database it showed on the page and then I inserted 2nd record, it showed two records on the page but when i inserted 3rd record into database, nothing is showing on the page I checked the console there is no error there then I inspected the page inside body tag this is showing only `<!---->` I viewed the page source there code is displaying fine, then I removed the 3rd record everything is fine after that I inserted third record again the content of page gone again, this is my code of page...

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 offset-md-2">
            @foreach ($questions as $question)
                <div class="card mb-2">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <h5 class="bold">{{ $question->question_title }}</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">{{ (strlen($question->question_body) > 50) ? substr($question->question_body, 0, 50) : $question->question_body }}</p>
                        <a href="questions/{{ $question->id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Continue Reading</a>
                        <p class="text-muted float-right">{{ date('M j, Y h:ia', strtotime($question->created_at)) }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

and here is the QuestionController:

```
public function index()
{
    $questions = Question::all();
    return view('questions.index', compact('questions'));
}
```

Comment: in your controller, try dd($questions); and see what you got.

Comment: Yeah bro there i'm getting 3 records

Comment: check your laravel log... storage/logs/laravel.log. Let me know if you have any error there.

Comment: @Gabriel, write this in answer and i will accept it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out the issue, do this two things:

1. use dd() function in your controller and check the data

> dd($questions)

2. check if there are any error in the Laravel log

> storage/logs/laravel.log

Hope that help you find the problem and possible fix.

Comment: Thank you so much bro I checked the `dd($questions)` then I got all record, after that I removed and run it again it has been fixed, miracley. :-)

Comment: More like cache issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an issue with your html.Take your `@foreach` statement out and place it just before `<div class="row">`. If that works, you'll know that its in html.
Oh and adjust `@endforeach` accordingly.